# Create a UserForm in Outlook to select from a list of templates to create an email

Tags: outlook, radio-button, userform, email-templates

I've created a UserForm in Outlook that allows me to select which email Template I want created.  The VBA for the email Templates work fine in creating the emails, however, when I use the code below in the UserForm, the emails are not created?  Am I missing some additional coding in the UserForm?

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If OptionButton1 Then

```
    Call QueueTrackingemail   'Module 2
```

ElseIf OptionButton2 Then

```
    Call DailyReportsEmail    'Module 3
```

ElseIf OptionButton3 Then

```
    Call CaptureListingEmail  'Module 4
```

ElseIf OptionButton4 Then

```
    Call EmmasEmail           'Module 5
```

ElseIf OptionButton5 Then

```
    Call MondayAgingEmail     'Module 6
```

ElseIf OptionButton6 Then

```
    Call Email672100          'Module 7
```

ElseIf OptionButton7 Then

```
    Call Email672200          'Module 8
```

End If

End Sub

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Is the macro sub called?

Comment: All the macros runs fine with no errors reported.  When I include with a MsgBox to verify the process, I get the MsgBox showing the action, but still no email is created. ?????

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this solved but you need to add `a = True` in between the OptionButtonX and the Then e.g.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If OptionButton1 = True Then
    Call QueueTrackingemail   'Module 2

ElseIf OptionButton2 = True Then
    Call DailyReportsEmail    'Module 3
```

etc..  You will need to add command button that runs it once you have clicked on at OptionButton.